# Remove maximum value of a list in haskell using recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am new to functional programming. I want to implement a method that removes the max element from a list of Ints, or if there are duplicates of the max element, just remove one of them using recursion. E.g., [2, 1, 4, 4, 3] should become [2, 1, 4, 3]. Without sorting the list.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please try to write a solution, and then ask a question if you run into any problems. At the moment, this is not a question. This also looks like homework.

Comment: Why not do it in two steps: First, find the max, second, modify the list? Should be O(n)

Comment: `deleteMax xs = delete (maximum xs) xs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The findMax function computes the maximum element of list, and removeMax removes the first occurrence of maximum element. You can glue them together to compute what you are looking for.

```
findMax :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
findMax [] acc = acc
findMax (h : rest) acc
  | h > acc = findMax rest h
  | otherwise = findMax rest acc


removeMax :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
removeMax []  mx = []
removeMax (h : rest) mx
  | h == mx = rest
  | otherwise = h : removeMax rest mx  

λ> findMax [2, 1, 4, 4, 3] 0
4
λ> removeMax [2, 1, 4, 4, 3] 4
[2,1,4,3]
λ>
```